# tensorflow2 problem of loading pb file to predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Currently, I'm using tf2.3 and windows 10 for learning siamese network. The training processing had no problem. I saved the model in pb format by using the **model.fit** and **model.save**.

Then, I used **tf.keras.models.load_model("model_pb",custom_objects={'tf': tf})** to load model and followed by **model.predict**.

The **model.summary()** information can be printed out, but with the message:**UserWarning: model is not loaded, but a Lambda layer uses it. It may cause errors.** The prediction only shows 0.5 as the result even with different pairs of images, maybe this is caused by unsuccessful model loading (I guess).

So,could you please tell me how to load the pb model correctly with the lambda layer? or maybe I did something else wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my model saving code

```
    '''training and validation code end here'''
model.fit(get_batch(batch_size),
              validation_data = nway_one_shot(model, n_way, n_val),
              epochs = epochs
        )


model.save("/face_recognizer/model_pb")
```

Here is my simple_onepair_test.py code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_pb",custom_objects={'tf': tf})
new_model.summary()



imagepath1 = "/face_recognizer/train/s3/1.jpg"
imagepath2 = "/face_recognizer/train/s3/2.jpg"
imagepath = "/face_recognizer/train/s44"

'''
turn the input1 image into tensor
'''
image1 = tf.io.read_file(imagepath1)
image_tensor1 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image1,3)
image_tensor1 = tf.image.resize(image_tensor1,[100,100])
image_tensor1= image_tensor1/255
image_tensor1 = tf.cast(image_tensor1,dtype = tf.float32)

'''
#turn the input2 image into tensor
'''
image2 = tf.io.read_file(imagepath2)
image_tensor2 = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image2,3)
image_tensor2 = tf.image.resize(image_tensor2,[100,100])
image_tensor2 = image_tensor2/255
image_tensor2 = tf.cast(image_tensor2,dtype = tf.float32)

'''
#expand dims for inputs
'''
image1=tf.expand_dims(image_tensor1,axis=0)
image2 = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor2,axis=0)
temp=[]
temp.append(image1)
temp.append(image2)
'''
#predict the image
'''
result = new_model.predict(temp, verbose=1)
print(result)
```

Here is the printed information

```
UserWarning: model is not loaded, but a Lambda layer uses it. It may cause errors.
 

 , UserWarning)
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 100, 100, 3) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 100, 100, 3) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)         (None, 512)          17349824    input_1[0][0]
                                                                 input_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 512)          0           sequential[0][0]
                                                                 sequential[1][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 2048)         1050624     lambda[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1024)         2098176     dense_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 512)          524800      dense_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            513         dense_4[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 21,023,937
Trainable params: 21,015,489
Non-trainable params: 8,448
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
[[0.5]]
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `model.predict()` before doing `model.save()`  and comparing if the resutls are the same?

Comment: @papaya Thank you so much, I checked and modified the code. But the **UserWarning** is stil there, could  you please tell me possible reasons for that?

Comment: Can you give the code about the structure of your model ?

Comment: @DachuanZhao pretty much the same as [link](https://medium.com/@prabhnoor0212/siamese-network-keras-31a3a8f37d04), and I changed the simple convnet into vgg16.